# What is the command for getting the list of Consumers of a particular topic in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I know we can get the list of consumer groups and then pass any one of he consumer group to a particular topic to determine the consumers offset.

Step 1: Use the following command to get list of consumer groups

```
kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper <Server-URL> --list
```

From the list of consumers obtained, pick a consumer group
Step 2: Get that particular consumer offset for a particular topic

```
kafka-consumer-offset-checker --zookeeper <Server-URL> --topic <topic-name> --group <group-name>
```

Same thing for bootstrap server.

But in a single step i need a command to get list of consumers for a particular topic.

Comment: There isn't such a command. You would need the `group.id` at a minimum. You cannot list all groups for a topic being consumed. This is one of the reasons Hortonworks made a tool for this https://hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-hortonworks-streams-messaging-manager-smm/

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no direct command to do that:

One workaround for this could be to list all consumer groups

```
~ $ $KAFKA_DIR/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh -bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -list
consumer-group-1
consumer-group-2
consumer-group-3
```

Then describe the consumer group using the below command which will show the topic.

```
~ $ $KAFKA_DIR/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --bootstrap-server 0.0.0.0:9092 --group consumer-group-1

TOPIC                        PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                     HOST            CLIENT-ID
topic-1                      0          -               0               -               consumer-1-9bf71d08-bcf8-4eb1-adb8-91589fd034b3 /11.2.9.159     consumer-1
```

Answer (score 3):

A way to extract this for all consumer is retrieve from the `__consumer_offsets` topic the list of topics/consumers.

I did a script to do so, it's quite slow to get the list but does the job

https://gist.github.com/padilo/6a5101f9e005c975956208cb19ba9f67